# yup formik validation text showing at the bottom of the screen

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have the following code which is making use of the formik yup validation.However, the error message is displayed at the bottom of the page and not just below the text field.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, Form, withFormik} from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import {Message} from 'primereact/message';
import axios from "axios/index";
import styled from "styled-components";
import AutoCompletion from "../AutoCompletion";
import {Button} from "primereact/components/button/Button";

const Label = styled.label`
    line-height: 31px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
`

const Input = styled(Field)`
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
`



const AddForm = ({
    values,
    props,
    errors,
    touched,
    isSubmitting,
    setFieldValue,
    handleChange,
    handleReset,
    handleSubmit,
    onCancel
}) => (
    <Form>
        <div className="p-grid">
            <div className="p-col-12 p-md-6 p-lg-4">
                <Label>Project Name</Label>
                <Input name="name"/>{touched.name && errors.name && <Message severity="error" text={errors.name}/>}
            </div>
           
        </div>
        <div className="button-set">
            <Button label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" style={{marginRight: '.25em', marginTop: '.25em'}}/>
            <Button label="Cancel" icon="pi pi-times" className="p-button-secondary" onClick={onCancel}/>
        </div>
    </Form>
)

export const FormikApp = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues: (props) => ({
            id: props.project && props.project.id || null,
            name: props.project && props.project.name || ''
           
    }),
    //Area where field validation is performed
    validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
   
        name: Yup.string().required('Project Name is required'),
       
    }),
    handleSubmit(values, { props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) {
        const id = values.id || 0;//If add new record, id will be null
        if (id > 0) { //Update
           //some code to update
        }
        else { //Add
            //some code to add
        }
        // resetForm()
        setSubmitting(false)
    }
})(AddForm)
```

When I hit the `Save` button without putting anything in the `Project Name` field, the error message is displayed at the bottom left of the screen in red color. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Why it is not displaying just below the `text` field?

[image]

Comment: How does you index.js file looks like? Does component in witch you are using this FormikApp component has any css?

Comment: You mean this one `const Input = styled(Field) display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;`? The code that I posted above is the form based component where I used FormikApp.